# JS Datatables - Toggle Show/Hide with responsive auto showing other columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a responsive Datatable that also has the Show/Hide columns feature enabled. 
I've noticed that whenever I hide a column using the show/hide buttons, a new column will automatically appear in order to fill the width of the page.

Is there a way to disable this so that if I toggle a column to hide, another column does not try and fill its place, but the existing columns will just fit the width of the page?

A test case of my current issue can be found here: http://live.datatables.net/huruwaro/1/edit

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try to redraw the table after clicking the button

```
$('#myTable1').DataTable().clear().draw();
```

or

```
$('#myTable1').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
```

or

```
$('#myTable1').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(false);
```

Comment: Sorry I tried the the last two solutions but Datables still tries to fill space with another column when one is removed. I'm unable to try the first solution because my data is populated via an ajax request which is also tied to other portions of the dashboard.